# Wikidata: How to query for the "language" of an "official name" (P1448) via SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

When editing the attribute "official name" (P1448, https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1448) of an item the editor has to specify the language. However, this is done via a combobox and nor via a qualifier.

See for instance the item "Szczawno-Zdrój" (Q1001231, https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1001231). One "official name" is "Бад-Зальцбрун" and the language for this value is Belarusian; however the language is not specified via a qualifier like e.g. "start time".

How can the 'pseudo-qualifier' "language" of "official name" be queried for via a SPARQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call "pseudo-qualifier" is the so-called **language tag**.

For specifying a language for a **constant string**, you can use `"my syting"@lang`. For example:

```
SELECT ?item
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P1448 "Бад-Зальцбрун"@be.
}
```

For specifying a language for a **variable string**, you can use the [`lang()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#func-lang) function in the query's *body*. For example:

```
SELECT ?officialName
WHERE {
  wd:Q1001231 wdt:P1448 ?officialName
              FILTER (lang(?officialName) = "be") .
}
```

For **querying** a string language, you can use the `lang()` function in the query's *head*. For example:

```
SELECT ?officialName (lang(?officialName) AS ?lang)
WHERE {
  wd:Q1001231 wdt:P1448 ?officialName .
}
```

References:

- [RDF 1.1 § 3.3 Literals](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#section-Graph-Literal)
- [SPARQL Query Language for RDF § 2.3.1 Matching Literals with Language Tags](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#matchLangTags)
- [SPARQL Query Language for RDF § 11.4.6 lang](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#func-lang)

Comment: from my understanding the TO wants the language name, not just the language tag. So we have to get via lang tag to language, e.g. `SELECT DISTINCT ?officialName ?langTag ?language ?languageLabel
WHERE {
  wd:Q1001231 wdt:P1448 ?officialName
  BIND (lang(?officialName) as ?langTag)
  ?language wdt:P31 wd:Q34770; wdt:P424 ?langTag
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}`

Comment: @UninformedUser Why don't you post it as an answer?